# How to Wrap content of <span> which is placed inside <td>

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I need to wrap content of `<span>` tag which is placed inside `<td>`, The style which I have applied is not wrapping.

Code:

```
<td style="white-space:nowrap:border:1px solid black">
<span style="display:block;white-space:pre-line;word-wrap:break-word;">
    Sries of 2 or more paragraph
</span>
```

Please note that I need to apply style without providing width property since `width` is dynamically configured by user.

Comment: create a demo with all the relevant code?

Comment: Formatting and spelling

Answer (score 0):

In html span is only made to contain text content. However, you can have nested html. Wordwrap only works when the element has a definite width. But, an span can not be provided a fixed width. So, it is better if you make a div with a certain width to wrap that span and provide wordwrap to that div only

Comment: I tried with removing <span> and placing <div> with above mentioned style , Still am facing same issue.
thing is i should not apply width property for the same code if i apply width its working.

Comment: <td style="word-wrap:break-word; white-space:pre-line; border:1px solid black"> <span style="">     try this

Comment: I tried with above suggested lines of code, but data is lost on right corner table is showing partial data